# How to expand the search environment variable %ProgramData% and use the start up info

Tags: c#, directory, environment-variables, python-3.5, programdata

I got `PythonApplication1.py` into the Sources of the C# Windows Form Application. On specific condition I write it into the Program Data folder this way:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"%ProgramData%\\Folder\\PythonApplication1.py", Resources.PythonApplication1);
```

and then with specific condition C#  runs Python Application from program data folder, this way:

```
Process.Start(@"%ProgramData%\\Folder\\PythonApplication1.py");
```

On the side of Python code I got second thing, it writes some data into the text document, which is located by the same path, but creation of it happens in Python itself, but it can be done from C# code, no matter, here:

```
path = (@"%ProgramData%\Folder\doc.txt")
```

but python code must write in this file by same program data path:

```
data = open (r'doc.txt', 'w')
```

and to write, just by same location, as both are there:

```
with open(r'doc.txt') as my_file:
```

The problem is, when I run this python code  as it shown above, this way:

```
 Process.Start(@"%ProgramData%\\Folder\\PythonApplication1.py");
```

It  does two wrong things, which does not happens, if it is not `%ProgramData%` directory and located with C# .exe in debug folder, just by `Process.Start("PythonApplication1.py");`, or if I run Python Code inside `%ProgramData%\Folder` path with doc.txt, just by hand. It creates and writes directly into the file, all is correct.

Otherwise if `Process.Start(@"%ProgramData%\\Folder\\PythonApplication1.py");` I got second result, it does not writes data into the doc.txt by `%ProgramData%\Folder` and python code creates it out of program data folder in debug folder with C# .exe.

So question is how to create and write from python code into the doc.txt  located by  C# Application  "%ProgramData%\Folder"  path.

Seems like, if PythonApplication1.py is exist inside ProgramData:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"%ProgramData%\\TAOZ\\PythonApplication1.py", Resources.PythonApplication1);
```

And if executed by hand it creates text document and writes to it, it must do the with `Process.Start`, but not.

also I tried to use star info, but not sure if this is correct, anyway I got same result:

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"%ProgramData%\\folder\\PythonApplication1.py");
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

So seems like I need two things here. To expand the search environment variable %ProgramData%. and also need to use the start up info to tell the process to start on that particular folder. Otherwise, the current working folder will be the same folder as application I guess, but not sure how to do it, and if it is reason of problem, need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a python program, you'll have to point to the python EXE. Assuming you have the pythonpath environment variable, this ought to work:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe"), Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%ProgramData%\folder\PythonApplication1.py"));
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%ProgramData%\folder\");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Hello, this way with `Process.Start(startInfo);` I got this ` Win32Exception was unhadled. An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll`

Comment: Since it's a .py file, I suspect you have to pass that as an argument of the python exe. Only just saw the .py ending :)

Comment: not sure what is wrong, but I got same exception massage this way too. at this moment I have no PythonApplication1.exe and have only PythonApplication1.py but if it works with local path it should woks this way too, right. but something is wrong

Comment: Is there more information inside the exception? Did you try directly referencing the python exe (mine is at C:\Python34\python.exe)?

Comment: I have not any python.exe, becouse I'm not sure how to create it for now, but  I got C:\ProgramData\folder\PythonApplication1.py there, which works if I call it  `Process.Start("PythonApplication1.py");` just from debug folder of project, but does not works from location above with your code. So I need to create PythonApplication1.exe to make it work? But if it the same code in .py why I can't run it just like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129862/discussion-between-john-and-timr).